# Windows 98 connected to a Linux box with a crossover cable...easy as it sounds?

Tags: linux, networking, windows-98, crossover-cable

I have a bunch of 5.25" floppies that I need to transfer files off of. The machine that I will be doing this from runs Windows 98 and does not have a USB port. It does have a CAT-5 network plug-in. I'd like to connect a crossover cable to my Linux box to transfer files from floppies mounted on the Win98 machine. What problems am I going to run into? How can I work around them? Happy to also use a laptop running Win8 instead of Linux if that would simplify things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1. Downvoted because this question shows no research effort. Instead of asking "what problems am I going to run into?" do basic research, try to connect and then ask a specific question *if* you run into a problem.

Comment: It's a Q&A site for questions with concrete answers. "What if"s are borderline, but many of them can have good answers anyway. (Especially for the questions that aren't explicitly asked...)

Comment: It's a bad question, but (1) yes, it's as easy as it sounds, if you know how to configure the network, and (2) use `putty` in the Windows 98 machine to transfer the files, and (3) all modern network cards (i.e. the one in the Linux box) can autodetect crossed/uncrossed cables, so you can use any ethernet cable you like.

Comment: ANSWER: ended up using a WinXP box to access the 5.25" floppies from Win98. General methods were 1)set static IP address to 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 w/common subnet on Win98 and XP machines, 2)set common workgroup, 3)set common local userid and pw on both machines, 4)enabled file sharing on Win98 C: drive. Used bonafide CAT5 crossover cable. Almost able to do this on Win8.1, stumped at "Windows security", "Enter network credentials" window with Win98 shared drive visible from Win8.1 box. All's well that ends well. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the Ethernet cards are able to establish a link, the OS will happily speak IP over it. The OS doesn't care about cable types, only the hardware does.

Your main concerns are, in this order:

#### Link layer

Use the correct cable. Many cards support auto-crossover (auto MDI-X) and will work with any cable type, as long as the feature is enabled on either end of a link. (However the data rate and duplex settings must be set to "auto" on both ends.)

But if one of the computers is *very* old then direct PC-to-PC connections might specifically need a cross-over cable. (If you use an Ethernet switch, that doesn't apply.)

#### Network layer

Configure the IP addresses correctly. If the "network" doesn't have a DHCP server (i.e. in a router or running on either machine), you'll have to configure static IP addresses (on the same subnet).

Using a DHCP server would make things easier as you can just use automatic address assignment. Using a router or a switch also means you can always use regular straight-through cables.

#### Application layer

Decide on the file transfer method – SMB ("File Sharing") might be the easiest, alternatives are SFTP (SSH file transfer) as well as traditional FTP.

On the Linux side you can set up *Samba* (smbd, nmbd) as a "Windows File Sharing" server, and access it from Windows. You will need to allow insecure logins using `ntlm auth = yes` (in rare cases even `lanman auth = yes`). This also applies to the opposite direction – when accessing Windows shares from Linux, Samba needs the `client ntlm auth` option.

The alternatives are SFTP (using WinSCP or FileZilla), or FTP using various clients.